# Substitute Special Characters in Word using Perl

Tags: perl

I can substitute almost all the special characters in a word except for the following:

```
">" - greater than symbol
"<" - less than symbol
"=" - equal to symbol
```

I can make other special characters that are meta characters like (+[]/) work by escaping them.

However, I cannot make the above 3 special characters work.

```
$word =~ s/[\>\<\=]//g; # Delete these special characters from the word
```

How do I substitute them? In my case, I am trying to delete or strip off the special characters from the word and these 3 symbols seem to be the only ones which I am not able to substitute.

Comment: I can't [reproduce](http://pastebin.com/GFBcXXQi) your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you don't need to escape these symbols even within the regex body, let alone when using them as a part of character class. This just works:

```
  my $test_string = '<my_word=some_word>';

  $test_string =~ s/[<>=]//g;
  # $test_string =~ s/<|>|=//g; is correct too, although a bit slower
  print $test_string; # my_wordsome_word
```

Still, it [works the same](http://codepad.org/uCcEHzdw) when written as in your example. So I guess the error is somewhere else in your code. Could you show more of it? )

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, your characters are not special in any way, so your code should just work.

I wanted to add that the substitution operator is perhaps not the best way to delete characters from a string. There's no need to invoke the power and complexity of the regex engine for this. I'd reach for the transliteration operator instead (see tr/// in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)).

```
$ perl -E'$ARGV[0]=~ tr/<>=//d; say $ARGV[0]; ' 'a<>=b'
ab
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special  about <, > and =, they are not meta-characters, so you don't even need to escape them

```
perl -E'$ARGV[0]=~ s{[<>=]}{}g; say $ARGV[0]; ' 'a<>=b'
```

gives me ab

Your problem comes from something else